# Check if the href attribute of certain a-tags matches the current page URL (with jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preventdefault

How can I check if the href attribute of certain a-tags matches the current page URL (with jQuery)? I want to remove all links that lead to the same page.
Here is the current state of my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="faq">
  <h2 class="sectionheading">FAQ</h2>
  <div class="accordion product" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <strong itemprop="name">
       Question 1               
      </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body schedule" itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer" style="display: none;">
      <p>Answer 1 <a href="www.test.de/test.html"></a></p>                
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion product" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <strong itemprop="name">
          Question 2                
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body schedule" itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer">
        <p>Answer 3 <a href="www.test.de/test.html"></a></p>                
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion product" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
      <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <strong itemprop="name">
            Question 3                
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body schedule" itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer">
          <p>Answer 3 <a href="www.test.de/test.html"></a></p>                
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#faq accordion-body a').each(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(a_href == $(location).attr('href')){
        $(this).preventDefault();
        $(this).css({
            'color' : 'black',
            'text-decoration' : 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

It should be addressed all a tags that are located within accordion-bodys (there are several). These should be deactivated first. Then the styling should be adjusted (with .css ()).

It does not work with my current code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: get current URL window.location.href function. Make sure to use regex to remove http:// from the url

Comment: Just one piece of advice - don't use the value you get from `$(this).attr("href")`.  Use `$(this)[0].href`.  The jQuery attribute function will return exactly what's in the link attribute, where the plain href value will give you an absolute Url.  That's more reliable... https://jsfiddle.net/mnh9q98b/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of your missing a `.` in `$('#faq accordion-body a')`, it should be `$('#faq .accordion-body a')`

Second you can use `a_href == window.location.href` to see if it match the current page.

```
$('#faq .accordion-body a').each(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(a_href == window.location.href){
        $(this).click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        })
        $(this).css({
            'color' : 'black',
            'text-decoration' : 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#faq .accordion-body a').each(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(a_href == window.location.href){
        $(this).click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        })
        $(this).css({
            'color' : 'black',
            'text-decoration' : 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faq">
  <h2 class="sectionheading">FAQ</h2>
  <div class="accordion product" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <strong itemprop="name">
       Question 1               
      </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body schedule" itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer" style="display: none;">
      <p>Answer 1 <a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js"></a></p>                
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion product" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <strong itemprop="name">
          Question 2                
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-body schedule" itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer">
        <p>Answer 3 <a href="www.test.de/test.html"></a></p>                
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion product" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
      <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <strong itemprop="name">
            Question 3                
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body schedule" itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer">
          <p>Answer 3 <a href="www.test.de/test.html"></a></p>                
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Codehan25 No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Carsten's reply, you can optimize it a bit by doing the following

```
$('#faq .accordion-body a[href="'+window.location.href+'"]').each(function(){
        $(this).css({
            'color' : 'black',
            'text-decoration' : 'none',
            'pointer-events' : 'none'
        });
    }
);
```

This makes it a tiny bit more concise and a bit faster too.

Comment: I chose Carsten Løvbo Andersen's solution. However, I did take the "pointer events: none" feature from your solution because I had not thought about it. Many Thanks :)

Comment: Glad you like it.

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tags in your code doesn't have hypertext `<a href="www.test.de/test.html"></a>` try adding some link text to see the below code in action.
And once the both urls matches in condition then you have to bind a click event with no default action (preventDefault() does that) for the current `a` tag, So then later whenever you click on that link it wont show default behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#faq').find('.accordion-body a').each(function(i,j){
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');

    if(a_href == $(location).attr('href')){

        $(this).on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
           });

        $(this).css({
            'color' : 'black',
            'text-decoration' : 'none'
        });
    }

    });

});
```